# Is it natural to struggle playing a new piano piece with slow progress in the beginning?

Tags: piano

I'm a self learner who had been playing consistently for about a year and half and then since then off and on for about a year, bringing us to present. I just want to know if my struggles are natural, even for someone with a few years of experience.

When I start out a new piece, probably an intermediate level piece, I'm really struggling in the beginning putting the notes together, getting my hands accustom to the positions of the piece. It really takes a while till I can start playing the notes together and with some rhythm. I've been playing for a few years now, and I feel like by now things should come a little bit more naturally and I can pick things up quicker.

Am I expecting too much too soon? Or should I be doing a bit better at this stage, and I need to work harder?

Comment: There's practise… and there's aptitude. Really, only a teacher who regularly sees your progress & knows your level in each, plus the difficulty of the piece, will have a proper handle on where you're lacking. All we can say at a remote is "practise more".

Comment: This will likely be closed as only opinionated answers could be given. We don't know you or your m.o., and whatever we say we get up to will/won't help. One will say they learn things easily, another that it's still difficult. Where does that leave us? More practice, more experience will always help - so do one and get the other! Oh, and, get a teacher - the only real, genuine answer!

Comment: @Tim. It's opinionated yes, but rather than closing, if people can share their honest experience, it would help me get an understanding and maybe also help some others who are wondering the same kind of thing.

Comment: "Sharing opinion" is not what this site is about. It's not a discussion forum, it's a question & answer site.

Comment: There is always some amount of difficulty, but as you’ve pointed out there is a question of what I call “shaping your ability”, or becoming accustomed to the movements required and strengthening the neural pathways. True for any physical task, it’s enhanced by repetition. Also, accept that everyone ‘begins’, and that training, whether self- or (better) with an experienced teacher, will help you to progress.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for inspiration and not opinions? If that is the case, my answer to your question is: Check out the book 'The Inner Game of Music' by Barry Green with W. Timothy Gallwey author of 'The Inner Game of Music'. I found it to be very supportive with the sort of question you are asking.